# My datatable doesn't work when using if else condition

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, datatables, codeigniter-3

master

I created a table that is equipped with jquery datatables on code igniter and sbadmin 2 theme, and I use if else condition to distinguish the admin table from the user table.

For the admin table it works fine, but for the user table strangely my datatables doesn't appear.

this is my js to invoke my datatables:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataTables').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
  </script>
```

this is my view code:

```
    <table class="table table-hover dataTables">
        <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Tanggal</th>
                <th scope="col">NIK</th>
                <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Room Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Meeting Start</th>
                <th scope="col">Meeting End</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <!-- no urutan table -->
            <?php $i = 1; ?>

            <?php foreach ($reserve->result_array() as $loopReserve) :

                $id_ruangan            = $loopReserve['id_ruangan'];
                $nama_ruangan          = $loopReserve['nama_ruangan'];
                $nik                   = $loopReserve['nik'];
                $user_id               = $loopReserve['user_id'];
                $nama_depan            = $loopReserve['nama_depan'];
                $nama_belakang         = $loopReserve['nama_belakang'];
                $meeting_start         = $loopReserve['meeting_start'];
                $meeting_end           = $loopReserve['meeting_end'];
                $keterangan            = $loopReserve['keterangan'];
                $is_cancel             = $loopReserve['is_cancel'];
                $cancel_by             = $loopReserve['cancel_by'];
                $cancel_date           = $loopReserve['cancel_date'];
                $alasan                = $loopReserve['alasan'];
                $created_date          = $loopReserve['created_date']
            ?>

                <tr class="text-center">
                    <?php if ($user['user_id'] == $user_id) : ?>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $i++; ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y', $created_date); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $nik; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $nama_depan . ' ' . $nama_belakang; ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $nama_ruangan; ?>
                        </td>

                        <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_start); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_end); ?></td>

                        <td>

                            <?php if (date('m/d/Y') == date('m/d/Y', $meeting_start)) : ?>

                                <?php if (date('m/d/Y H:i') < date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_start)) : ?>
                                    <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-warning">Noted</div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php elseif (date('m/d/Y H:i') >= date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_start) && date('m/d/Y H:i') <= date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_end)) : ?>
                                    <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-primary">Progress</div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-success">Done</div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php elseif (date('m/d/Y') > date('m/d/Y', $meeting_end)) : ?>

                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-success">Done</div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php else : ?>

                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-warning">Noted</div>
                                <?php endif ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="text-break mx-0"><?php echo $keterangan; ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if ($user['level_id'] == 1) : ?>
                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Edit</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Edit</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-ban"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Cancel</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php else : ?>
                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-ban"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Cancel</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </td>
                    <?php elseif ($user['level_id'] == 1) : ?>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $i++; ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y', $created_date); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $nik; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $nama_depan . ' ' . $nama_belakang; ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $nama_ruangan; ?>
                        </td>

                        <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_start); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_end); ?></td>

                        <td>

                            <?php if (date('m/d/Y') == date('m/d/Y', $meeting_start)) : ?>

                                <?php if (date('m/d/Y H:i') < date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_start)) : ?>
                                    <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-warning">Noted</div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php elseif (date('m/d/Y H:i') >= date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_start) && date('m/d/Y H:i') <= date('m/d/Y H:i', $meeting_end)) : ?>
                                    <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-primary">Progress</div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <div class="badge badge-success">Done</div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php elseif (date('m/d/Y') > date('m/d/Y', $meeting_end)) : ?>

                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-success">Done</div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php else : ?>

                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-danger">Cancel by <?php echo $cancel_by; ?></div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="badge badge-warning">Noted</div>
                                <?php endif ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="text-break mx-0"><?php echo $keterangan; ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if ($user['level_id'] == 1) : ?>
                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Edit</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Edit</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-ban"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Cancel</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php else : ?>
                                <?php if ($is_cancel == 1) : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 py-0 d-xl-inline mb-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewReserveModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> View</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger ml-2 px-2 py-0 d-none d-xl-inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelModal<?php echo $id_ruangan ?>"><small><i class="fas fa-fw fa-ban"></i><span class="d-none d-xl-inline"> Cancel</span></small></button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And this is my controller:

```
     public function reserve()
{
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['nik' =>

    $this->session->userdata('nik')])->row_array();
    $data['reserve'] = $this->Model_reserve->getReserve();
    $data['username'] = $this->Model_reserve->getUser();
    $data['meeting'] = $this->Model_reserve->viewMr();

    $data['title'] = 'Reserve';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('menu/reserve', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {

        $this->myReservation();
    }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
    public function getReserve()
{
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT  ruang_meeting.*, user.nama_depan, user.nama_belakang FROM ruang_meeting
                                JOIN user ON ruang_meeting.user_id = user.user_id ORDER BY ruang_meeting.id_ruangan DESC");
    return $result;
}
```

[i attach screenshoot user table view too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRyxr.png)

[and screenshot from admin table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKoL.png)

i dont know what wrong to my code, please help me.
thank you

Comment: Where is your JS that invokes DataTable?

Comment: sorry I forgot to post it, I have edited the post. thank you

Answer (score 0):

do you have a separate table from your admin to your user?
If so, check your DataTable initialization placing.

//Admin table code.

`<table id="adminTable" class="dataTables"/>`

// Datatable init

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dataTables').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    });

 </script>
```

//User table code.

`<table id="userTable" class="dataTables"/>`

Comment: no sir, my admin and user datatables are combined into one table in my php file called reserve.php, but in that file I distinguish which admin and which user use if else condition. I was able to separate each user and admin table too, but the results remain the same